# How to create posts on a static website without editing index.html?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have written a small blog-website just using HTML and CSS (and maybe Bootstrap for the styling). Now, the website should have blog posts in forms of articles that. How can I "create" new articles and update the website without having to manually edit the index.html file? What is the best way to go here?

Comment: The best way is to create website using WordPress

Comment: If you don’t want to implement anything “dynamic” yourself, then maybe go look into _static site generators_.